# What do you call someone who thinks everyone is flirting with them?

Tags: single-word-requests

I sat by someone at a party that insisted all the women were flirting with him. They were not.

Comment: Delusional comes to mind, but it's a little general...

Comment: I would call them egotistic.

Comment: *Wrong*? *Confused*? You need to provide the sense that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**conceited**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceited)

> Holding or characterized by an unduly high opinion of oneself; vain.

As in:

I sat by a **conceited** person at a party that insisted all the women were flirting with him.

Comment: I don’t think you can say ‘self’-conceited - because conceited already has the interest in self contained within it. But you could say ‘conceited’. Or, self-obsessed. Or ‘narcissistic ‘.

Comment: @Jelila  correct, so edited

Comment: Ok! @lbf ☺️ Cool